# Distributing A Set Number Of Points At Random Locations Within Acres On Map

Tags: asp.net, azure, maps, geospatial, azure-maps

I am trying to distribute a number of points per acre within a square mile using Azure maps. Currently, I have been looking into the haversine formula, trig, basic division, etc, but believe I may be overthinking it.

Any ideas?

Lets say I want 3 points put per acre within a square mile in randomized but appropriate lat/lng locations within each acre.

Right now it seems I need to divide up the X and Y by feet or yard and then divide into the lat/lng to get appropriate locations.

A bit ignorant of lat/lng distances. The information I have found says that a degree of lat, for example, is worth about 69 miles. Then it divides it into "seconds," etc, apparently. A bit confusing.

Ideas?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A square with sides of 63.61 meters is equal to one acre. To calculate random points within that square, start off with a latitude and longitude coordinate for a corner, then calculate opposite corners coordinates, then calculate the latitude/longitude widths and use that to calculate random offsets from the starting coordinate. For example, take coordinate 45, -110 and assume this is the top left corner of the square. The opposite corner would have a heading of 135 degrees, and the distance to the corner would be sqrt(a^2 + b^2) = sqrt(63.61^2 + 63.61^2) = 89.9581247 meters. Here is code that would calculate three random points within that square acre.

```
var lat = 45;
var lon = -110;

var cornerDistance = 89.9581247;
var cornerHeading = 135;

//Bottom right corner.
var cornerPosition = atlas.math.getDestination([lat, lon], cornerHeading, cornerDistance);

var latWidth = lat - cornerPosition[1]; //Corner is lower.
var lonWidth = cornerPosition[0] - lon; //Corner is to the right.

var randomPositions = [];

for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
    randomPositions.push(lon + Math.random()*lonWidth, lat - Math.random() * latWidth]);
}
```